# Replace corroded gas range line

Tags: plumbing, gas, stove, range

I’m attempting to replace a gas range line that has a pinhole leak. I disconnected it from the wall without issue but separating it from the stove itself is near impossible. I’ve tried a baking soda soak, WD-40, and a set of (newly purchased) large pipe wrenches, all without success.

Note I’m trying to counter-clockwise unscrew the male pipe from the female side on the range.

I don’t want to damage the oven components torquing on it too hard. Is it time to hire a plumber, or is this still a job I can finish on my own? Any suggestions for separating this fused connection?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are attempting to remove the wrong fitting.

Instead of using a pipe wrench where you have it, use an appropriate size open end wrench here:

[image]

Comment: Should only need to loosen the two nuts closest to pipe/tube/line first, then the narrow nut should turn off from the stove fitting.  The long nut on the pipe and short/narrow nut do come apart, but once loosen the narrow nut will turn without the pipe turning.

Comment: The nuts you are removing have "flare" metal to metal seals . No pipe dope should be used on the sealing surfaces when replacing them .